# URL Structure without slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This question is a combination of seo and the possibilities routes can give (i hope)

My models are:

```
class region
 has_many: cities
end

class city
belongs_to: region
has_many:activities
has_many:restaurants
has_many:shoppings

end

class activity
belongs_to:city

end

class restaurant
belongs_to:city
end

class shopping
belongs_to:city
end
```

Routes.rb

```
localized(['en', 'nl'], :verbose => true) do
scope "/:locale" do
resources :regions do 
  resources :cities do
  resources :restaurants do
    member do
    get 'photo'
    get 'reviews'
    get 'location'
  end
end
```

The url structure looks like this
/en/umbria/perugia/activities/citytour

After some seo research i need to minimize the levels so a better approach is this:

umbria/perugia-activities-citytour

Question:
Is this possibly in the routes config file and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually done this before, but here's a resource that seems to solve your problem:
http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=14799 (Posts 8 and 9 in particular)

Though the thread's a few years old, so there might be more up to date ways of doing this.

**Edit:** 
Also, this is a little bit off topic (because I'm pretty sure it won't help you with your question in particular; that's what the thread I posted above the Edit is for) but I've heard good things about it and figured it might be helpful with your SEO updates: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id. Basically it's a plugin that helps you form more readable urls.